# How to properly save data in GAE datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I need to keep data like below:

```
field1value=SomeStringValue
field1score=10
field2value=SomeOtherValue
field2score=20
...
fieldNvalue=SomeNValue
fieldNscore=N
```

i.e. I have N fields, each field has its own name, value stored there and score. How to properly store such data in GAE datastore? Data should be easily accessible by field name. I will also need to calculate final score (`field1score + field1score + ... + fieldNscore`).

N is around 100, total number of records in the database will be huge.

**Upd.** I've used the following approach, but looks like it is not the best one:

```
class User(db.Model):
    field_names = db.StringListProperty()
    field_values = db.StringListProperty()
    field_scores = db.ListProperty(int)
    score_value = db.IntegerProperty()

def fields_add(user_key_name, field_name, field_value, field_score):
    user = User.get(user_key_name)
    if user:
        field_names = user.field_names
        field_values = user.field_values
        field_scores = user.field_scores
        if field_name in user.field_names:
            field_index = user.field_names.index(field_name)
            field_values[field_index] = field_value
            field_scores[field_index] = field_score
        else:
            field_names.append(field_name)
            field_values.append(field_value)
            field_scores.append(field_score)
        user.field_names = field_names
        user.field_values = field_values 
        user.field_scores = field_scores
        # TODO: update user.score_value
        user.put()
```

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your access patterns. Knowing more details and requirements would allow a better answer.

If you will ever have more than 5000 entries that you cannot otherwise separate, you should use a simple structure like the one below. To get the sum of the scores, you can query all and add them in memory. If you have a large number of scores, you can either use [MapReduce](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/) to find the sum on demand, or a [shard counter](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters.html) to keep a running total.

```
class Score(db.Model):
  value = db.StringProperty()
  score = db.IntegerProperty()
```

You can use a `ListProperty` if you will not have more than 5000 entries. This will result in a much lower number of datastore reads and writes, since it's only one query to return all the results which you can then sum in memory. If you have some third piece of data (like the player field below) you can use to guarantee that you have less than 5000 entries, this may be a decent solution.

```
class Score(db.Model):
  player = db.StringProperty()
  values = db.StringListProperty()
  scores = db.ListProperty(int)
```

Comment: Total number of records in the datastore will be more than 5000. But  number of fields (`N` above) will be around 100.

Answer (score 0):

Probably depends on what your access patterns are like, and what the max value of N is.

The most simple method would be to maintain two [ListProperties](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#ListProperty):

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class MyClass(db.Model):
  valueList = db.StringListProperty()
  scoreList = db.ListProperty(int)
```

Comment: Thanks, Raven. What is about field names? Should I have 3rd list?

Comment: @LA_ If your list of field names is static you probably want to maintain a name<->index lookup and not even store them in the User class.  Just initialize everyone to the same size arrays with good defaults (zeros?).  But if you want to do any queries based on specific named scores you might want to consider explicitly listing each field instead of storing the values/scores in lists.  I'm pretty sure this could be done dynamically - no need to type in 200 properties (and perhaps the Expando model would be appropriate if the list of fields isn't static).